# Angular 5 subject in Material 2 Dialog

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material2

Im running into this strange error while implementing authentication for the mobile version of the navigation in a material 2 dialog.

I wrote an auth service, that takes care of validating a users token and storing the result in a subject:

```
  userSignedIn$: Subject<boolean> = new Subject();

  constructor(public authService: Angular2TokenService) {

    this.authService.validateToken().subscribe(
      res => res.status == 200 ? this.userSignedIn$.next(res.json().success) : this.userSignedIn$.next(false)
    )
  }
```

next, I have a function for launching the mobile navigation as a material 2 dialog (its a totally separate component for the mobile nav):

```
 //the event listener is used to trigger the login/signup dialog and shouldn't be the problem here
 presentMobileMenuDialog(): void {
    let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(MobileMenuComponent, {
      height: '100%',
      width: '100%',
      maxWidth: '100vw',
      panelClass: 'deine-mutter'
    });

    const sub = dialogRef.componentInstance.onClick.subscribe(action => {
      this.presentAuthDialog(action)
    });
  }
```

next thing is my mobile-menu component, nothing special here:

```
export class MobileMenuComponent implements OnInit {
  onClick = new EventEmitter<string>();
  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<MobileMenuComponent>,
    //initializing the authService which will be used in the html template
    public authService: AuthService,
    private router: Router,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  closeMenu(){
    this.dialogRef.close()
  }

  //for triggering login and signup dialog (not part of the problem, but I left it just in case im missing something)
  presentAuthDialog(mode) {
    this.closeMenu()
    this.onClick.emit(mode)
  }

  //basic routing and closing the dialog
  forward(link){
    this.closeMenu();
    this.router.navigate([link]);
  }


  logout() {
    this.closeMenu()
    this.authService.logOutUser().subscribe(() => this.router.navigate(['/']));
  }
```

on we go to the html template, which is where the problem is:

```
<div class="mobile-menu fluid-container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 close">
      <mat-icon (click)="closeMenu()">close</mat-icon>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 search">
      <app-search></app-search>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 menu-items">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" id="coins" (click)="forward('/coins')">Coins</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link"(click)="forward('/global')">Global Stats</a>
        </li>
        <li *ngIf="(authService.userSignedIn$ | async)" class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" id="profile" (click)="forward('/profile')">Profile</a>
        </li>
        <li *ngIf="(authService.userSignedIn$ | async)" class="nav-item">
          <a (click)="logout()" class="nav-link">Logout</a>
        </li>
        <li *ngIf="!(authService.userSignedIn$ | async)" class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" (click)="presentAuthDialog('login')" >Login</a>
        </li>
        <li *ngIf="!(authService.userSignedIn$ | async)" class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" (click)="presentAuthDialog('register')">Register</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So the problem I'm having is, that no matter if I'm logged in or not, the menu will always show login and register. What puzzles me, is that I use the same authService and ngIf argument in the desktop version of the navigation and it works as expected, the only difference being, that its not implemented inside of a material 2 dialog. I played around with this for quite a while now and tried the following and always printed the expected boolean, how ever the frontend template (changed to *ngIf="userLogedIn") wouldn't make the expected changes.

```
//shortend the class because this is getting way to long already
userLogedin: boolean = false;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.checkAuthStatus();
  }

  presentAuthDialog(mode) {
    this.dialogRef.close()
    this.onClick.emit(mode)
    this.checkAuthStatus()
  }

  logout() {
    this.dialogRef.close()
    this.authService.logOutUser().subscribe(() => this.router.navigate(['/']));
    this.checkAuthStatus();
  }

  checkAuthStatus(){
    this.authService.userSignedIn$.subscribe(data => {
      this.userLogedin = data;
      console.log(data)
    })
  }
```

So I'm pretty confused why this is happening and sorry that this has became so long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns our when using a BehaviorSubject in the authService everything works as expected. Reading the docs again, it sure makes a lot more sense to use BehaviorSubject. Im still not sure, why it worked for the other nav though.

Updated Service:

```
 userSignedIn$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

  constructor(public authService: Angular2TokenService, private http: Http) {

    this.authService.validateToken().subscribe(
      res => res.status == 200 ? this.userSignedIn$.next(res.json().success) : this.userSignedIn$.next(false)
    )
  }
```